# How to secure kubectl access?

Tags: security, kubernetes

How to secure `.kube/config`, so that even if our computer containing that file is compromised, our cluster is still secure?

e.g. It's not as straightforward as running `kubectl delete deployment` to delete our deployment (assuming we are the super admin in RBAC)

Comment: store you config in some encrypted store like vault , pull it on demand , use it and then delete it

Comment: Is it possible to auto delete/expire?

Comment: From https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/ OAuth seems to support expiration. But as allways you can still manually/automated create new users every x days and store the new credentials in a vault.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this, in case your machine gets compromised and you want to disable access to the cluster. Note that no solution will prevent a small window where a hacker can gain access and do some damage.

- [OIDC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#option-1-oidc-authenticator) authentication (OpenID Connect). Mitigation -> Disable the OIDC user on the OIDC provider and enable a lifetime for the session in the OIDC provider.
- [Webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#webhook-token-authentication) authentication. Mitigation -> disable client certs on the webhook service and the token lifetime is controlled by `--authentication-token-webhook-cache-ttl` which defaults to 2 minutes. In this case, the webhook service manages the tokens on your K8s cluster.
- [Authenticating Proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#authenticating-proxy). Mitigation -> disable users on the proxy.
- [Client Go credential plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins). Mitigation -> Disable user in the provider where the plugin is authenticating with. For example, the [AWS IAM Authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) uses this, so you would delete or disable the IAM user on AWS.